# Troubleshooting Strange Pseudo CSS Bug

Tags: css, z-index, pseudo-class, cross-browser

I'm working on a unique project for work. The problem I'm running into is that I only have control over the CSS stylesheet used on this project and I'm tasked with really altering the layout of it, which is fine. But, I'm running into a weird issue with this "Seal" link button.

Originally, they had an image as the background and the link that opens a pop-up window to select the Seal, that is triggered from an  that is inside #searchSeal

It works in newer browsers but I need to support IE8+ and in those browsers, the link is only click on the outer rim of the button and if you mouse-over the :after I created for the button that is really just a placeholder for the button's text... then the link drops.

Please help if you can! CSS in question is below and I'm probably just missing the issue.

Thanks!!

```
#divSeal {
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 290px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 176px;
    height: 41px;}

#searchSeal {
    z-index: 3;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 30px; 
    width: 176px;
    height: 40px; 
    border: 1px solid #B18D44; 
    color: white;
    background: #F9D791;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;}

#searchSeal:hover {
    background: #B18D44;
    color: #004AFF;}

#searchSeal:after {
    content: "Choose Seal";
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 176px;
    height: 40px;
    font: bold 24px Arial;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #B18D44;}

#searchSeal a, #_ctl0_ContenPlaceHolderContent_hSearchSeal {
    z-index: 500;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    text-decoration: none;}
```

Thanks for any and all help guys!!

Comment: Where's the HTML? Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ / http://jsbin.com/ demo?

Comment: Added a quick jsfiddle that has all the stuff in it. Thanks!!

On a time crunch with this: http://jsfiddle.net/YAgCt/

I DO NOT control the HTML though...

Comment: Any chance we can see the site in context? I'm having trouble reading your post too... looks like it was edited once or twice and bits are missing/added

Comment: When I hover on the button, nothing weird happens in IE9 in IE8 mode. I even booted my virtual machine containing genuine IE8 to test, and still nothing weird. Does your test case definitely reproduce the problem?

Comment: Just curious, but :after will only work in IE8 with a proper `<!DOCTYPE>`. You've got that sorted, right?

Comment: I ended up fixing the bug via a workaround. This had a hard deadline so, sorry I didn't check back for comment reviews... check for quick answers and then just tried to solve it.